# To "promote and/or demote" as a single, common verb or term

Tags: word-request, terminology

It's a bit similar to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/445742/a-common-term-for-promote-demote) but not in the school related sense they've asked. I haven't found any sources on that and there's a chance that no such term exists. In such case, I'll be happy with that being confirmed and extra bonus if someone witty can make up one implying such a meaning.

Suppose there are two separate buttons, labelled *promotion* and *demotion* (or *to promote* and *to demote*). Now, we reconstruct the user interface so that there's only a single button. One way is to be super explicit and labeled it *promotion or demotion* but that creates problems (one being the size of it, as it's clunky and awkward, second one being that the order of terms may affect the user's choice).

Previously, the promotion or demotion occurred immediately. Now, we want to push the subject for a change in their status and decide the magnitude and direction later.

For now, I went with *elevation* (as we're talking sort of setting elevation of privileges). However, as I want to indicate that the there's a current elevation (level, status) already set (while the operation will **re**set it), I lean towards *to reelevate*. To me, it looks atrociously unnatural.

Comment: I suggest that the word mentioned in your request, **status**, seems to fit. Is there a good reason why it has to be a verb?

Comment: @Mari-LouA It doesn't have to be verb (although it'd be more congruent with the rest of the interface). One could see *status* as a verb, too (*to set status*, *to restatus*, *to statusify*, sort of). Regrettably, *status* is a separate concept and can't be applied. I'd need something more one-dimensional (with rather obvious up and down direction).

Comment: **Hierarchy** perhaps? If it's for a company, then you might want to go with **reorganisation**.

Comment: You're talking about changing permissions. Are you using a *NIX-based system? If so, then why not Set Perms? That's pretty *NIX-standard.

Comment: @FeliniusRex Doesn't have to be *NIX. Might be Win*, hehe... Regardless, the concept of *permission* is not one-dimensional. One could have permission X while someone else might have permission Y. In my case, we're talking strictly about promoting and demoting along a single privilege path, so to speak. It's very much *bump up (along X)*, not *bump to X*. I'm starting to sense that there's no such a term, which is disappointing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any single verb that includes both "promote" and "demote".

One could use "change" as a verb here:

> - Change rank
> - Change status
> - Change level
> - Change permissions

"set" could also be used as a verb, as a comment suggests. So could "alter"/

Note that "change height" includes both "raise" and "lower" (as verbs).